# Java: How to convert a File object to a String object in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

I have a html file which I want to use to extract information. For that I am using Jsoup.
Now for using Jsoup, I need to convert the html file into a string. How can I do that?

```
File myhtml = new File("D:\\path\\report.html")';
```

Now, I want a String object that contains the content inside the html file.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file

Comment: Read the file character by character and put each character in a StringBuffer.  When done ask the StringBuffer for the string.

Comment: Check jsoup api. It has `parse` method that takes file. You don't need to read file content manually.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use [apache common IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to read a text file into a single string

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

simple and "clean". you can even set encoding of the text file with no hassle.

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: How would you do the opposite... readStringToFile

Comment: Attached link is expired, can you please post latest URL?

Comment: FileUtils.readFileToString is now deprecated with Java 8. It is no longer recommended to use this way.

Answer (score 13):

Use a library like [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) or [Commons / IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). They have oneliner methods.

Guava:

```
Files.toString(file, charset);
```

Commons / IO:

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(file, charset);
```

Without such a library, I'd write a helper method, something like this:

```
public String readFile(File file, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), charset);
}
```

Comment: `Files.toString` is `@Deprecated`, so the modern way in `Guava` call `Files.asCharSource(file, charset).read()`.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi
yep. impossible to keep up with Guava's deprecation cycle, thanks

Answer (score 8):

With Java 7, it's as simple as:

```
final String EoL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
        Charset.defaultCharset());

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : lines) {
    sb.append(line).append(EoL);
}
final String content = sb.toString();
```

However, it does havea few minor caveats (like handling files that does not fit into the memory).

I would suggest taking a look on [corresponding section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html) in the official Java tutorial (that's also the case if you have a prior Java).

As others pointed out, you might find sime 3rd party libraries useful (like Apache commons I/O or Guava).

Answer (score 4):

Readin file with file inputstream and append file content to string.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyOffileInputStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //File file = new File("./store/robots.txt");
        File file = new File("swingloggingsscce.log");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        String str = "";

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                str += (char) content;
            }

            System.out.println("After reading file");
            System.out.println(str);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all contents of `myhtml` to `String` as follows:

```
Scanner myScanner = null;
try
{
    myScanner = new Scanner(myhtml);
    String contents = myScanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next(); 
}
finally
{
    if(myScanner != null)
    {
        myScanner.close(); 
    }
}
```

Ofcourse, you can add a `catch` block to handle exceptions properly.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Jsoup has method that takes file: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score -1):

Why you just not read the File line by line and add it to a StringBuffer?

After you reach end of File you can get the String from the StringBuffer.