# How to download a file which is not readable in android?

Tags: java, android, file, download

For school, I'm working on an android app which is supposed to deal with some files. I've done the code app by putting files into the assets folder. 
Now the problem is that the files need to be updated by getting replaced by the file from an URL of this shape : "http://ade6-ujf-ro.grenet.fr/jsp/custom/modules/plannings/anonymous_cal.jsp?resources=1120&projectId=2&calType=ical&firstDate=2018-03-30&lastDate=2018-03-30".
I've tried a lot of download functions that I found here but they are all dealing with text files which they get from the URL and write, line per line, them down to the internal/external storage.
So my question is, how can I download the file to an "app folder" on the internal storage. 
Thank you so much for your future help !

Answer (score 0):

Convert your file to String.And encrypt it with your password.

How to convert a File object to a String object in java?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12559960/6533179